# lightning:inputField styling on picklist data type - strange format

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

With the below markup, the output is as per the screenshot. This is incorrect because the picklist values should all be displaying when one selects the field, instead of them being displayed on a single line. I am perplexed why this is happening (because the equivalent in Visualforce is correct - when one selects a picklist field then the values will all appear one under the other).

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="0011t00000r5BJxAAM" objectApiName="Account">
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="ex1" value="" fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="field1" value="" fieldName="Football_Club__c"  />
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="field2" value="" fieldName="Football_Club_City__c" />
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="field3" value="" fieldName="Football_Club_City_Concat__c" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Also I see 4 inputFields in your markup but only 3 inputs and one output on the page. Are all of football related fields picklists? Is there some controller logic running? Or is that all of the code?Try putting <lightning:messages /> under the recordeditform tag and see if you get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshots posted in the question show how it looks like in an Lightning App for a preview. All I had to do was to create a Lightning override so that it inherits the Salesforce styling.

I forgot that Lighting Apps don't by default inherit the Salesforce styling.